# g++ cross compile to windows from linux

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, g++, cross-compiling

Im trying to cross compile a c++ application to windows from linux. I want to be able to use the normal g++ compiler as I have always used.

I tried looking online for help on this issue and found only mingw or clang stuff or stuff with a long complex setup.

Is there like a one line command I can use like g++ -windows to get it to build a windows executable right there. My code doesnt use any windows libaries so should compile just fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your code most definitely at least uses a libc and libc++. So no, there is no single command version. I recommend using MXE. https://mxe.cc/

Answer (score 0):

Is really not that hard. The only thing you need to do is install `g++-mingw-w64` with:

```bash
sudo apt install g++-mingw-w64 -y
```

After that, the only thing you need to do is compile with:

```bash
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ hello.c -o hello.exe
```

That is going to give you a 64-bit executable for windows that just runs. That's how I do it and I haven't had any problems.

If you want a 32-bit executable just do:

```bash
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ hello.c -o hello.exe
```